# Can't get the response when passing data of email as user@something.com to web api

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rest, web-services

if entering email like "example@gmail.com" ajax not is not giving response, while it 's working when we are not using '@' symbol in email. but we are able to insert values successfully in database. we have tried all the possibilities we can but we were able to find this problem and we are not able to solve this please help us

```js
//register.php client side file

function insertUser()  //funcion call through onclick event

{ 
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value; //getting values from //FORM 
    var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    $.ajax({
        url: "user/", //url to call
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            view: 1,
            name: name,
            mobile: mobile,
            email: email,
            password: password

        }),
        success: function(data) { //we are not getting response when using @ symbol in email

            console.log(data);

            if (data.haserror == 1) {
                alert(data.haserror);
            } else {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data.error);
        }
    });

}
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
filename: UserRestHandler.php
public
function RegisterUser($data) { //this is a server side response code

    $user = new User();
    $rawData = $user - > RegisterUser($data);

    if (empty($rawData)) {
        $statusCode = 404;
        $rawData = array('error' => 'No users found!');
    } else {
        $statusCode = 200;
    }

    $requestContentType = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
    $this - > setHttpHeaders($requestContentType, $statusCode);

    if (strpos($requestContentType, 'application/json') !== false) {
        $response = $this - > encodeJson($rawData);
        echo $response;
    } else if (strpos($requestContentType, 'text/html') !== false) {
        $response = $this - > encodeHtml($rawData);
        echo $response;
    } else if (strpos($requestContentType, 'application/xml') !== false) {
        $response = $this - > encodeXml($rawData);
        echo $response;
    }
}
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
//server side code filename: RestController.php
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
header("Content-type:application/json");

require_once("MobileRestHandler.php");
require_once("UserRestHandler.php");
$view = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
 $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
if(isset($json["view"]))
{

 $view = $json["view"];

/* controls the RESTful services URL mapping */
 switch($view)
 {

  case "all":
   // to handle REST Url /user/list/
   $userRestHandler = new UserRestHandler();
   $userRestHandler->getAllUsers();
   break;

  case "userid":
   // to handle REST Url /user/show/<id>/
   $userRestHandler = new UserRestHandler();
   $userRestHandler->getUser($json['id']);
   break;

     case "1":
   // to handle REST Url /user/list/
   $userRestHandler = new UserRestHandler();
   $result=$userRestHandler->RegisterUser($json);
   break;

        case "0":
   // to handle REST Url /user/list/
   $userRestHandler = new UserRestHandler();
   $userRestHandler->DeleteUsers($json);
   break;

  case "2":
   // to handle REST Url /user/show/<id>/
   $userRestHandler = new UserRestHandler();
   $userRestHandler->UpdateUsers($json);
   break;

  case "" :
   //404 - not found;
   break;
 }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: so, what you're saying is, the server side doesn't like the @ character in an email? what if you use @ in any other field? The server side code is not helpful, you haven't shown the code that handles the request, only the code that sends a response ... surely it's the code that handles the request that is failing - have you checked the logs for your server code to see if there's anything useful there?

Comment: sir now we have edited the code with file name please check

Comment: @JaromandaX yes @ character is working in name field but not in email feild, and in html we have also tried changing input type to text from email.

Comment: yuo still haven't added the code that actually handles data sent to the server